# Cannot create the connection to Oracle XE Database in Oracle SQL Developer ("Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection")

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-connection

My setup:
OS - Oracle Linux 8,
Oracle XE 21c,
Oracle SQL Developer 22.2.1

I already set up the database with this code:

```
cd /etc/init.d/; sudo ./oracle-xe-21c configure
```

And I wanted to create a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer with the database.

But I keep getting the error `"Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because your database is not running. To check if this is the case, run the following command:

```
cd /etc/init.d/; sudo ./oracle-xe-21c status
```

Then if `"Oracle Database status"` is `"STOPPED"`, NOT `"RUNNING"`, you can run the following to start the database:

```
cd /etc/init.d/; sudo ./oracle-xe-21c start
```

Also, make sure you have the following input when setting up a new connection:

[image]

where the password is the one you use to login to your system.

[Source](https://www.oracle.com/be/database/technologies/appdev/xe/quickstart.html#Connecting%20to%20Oracle%20Database%20XE)